# i have problem when i want extend django user model

Tags: django

i build simple django project and i have model class is structure and i want link structure with user django in objective to give multiple access for different structure , the problem that when i make python3 manage.py make migrations all is fine and with migrate also is fine with sqlmigrate is fine but in database i don't find the Utilisateur table

```
from immob.models import Division
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Utilisateur(models.Model):
user=models.OneToOneField('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Division=models.ForeignKey(Division,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

MacBook-Pro-de-MAC:Invest_App mac$ python3 manage.py sqlmigrate compte 0001

### BEGIN;

### -- Create model Utilisateur

```
CREATE TABLE "compte_utilisateur" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "Division_id" integer NOT NULL, "user_id" integer NOT NULL UNIQUE);
ALTER TABLE "compte_utilisateur" ADD CONSTRAINT "compte_utilisateur_Division_id_191feb84_fk_immob_division_id" FOREIGN KEY ("Division_id") REFERENCES "immob_division" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
ALTER TABLE "compte_utilisateur" ADD CONSTRAINT "compte_utilisateur_user_id_9142a9fe_fk_auth_user_id" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
CREATE INDEX "compte_utilisateur_Division_id_191feb84" ON "compte_utilisateur" ("Division_id");
COMMIT;
```

but in database i don't find UTilisateur Table ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from immob.models import Division
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Utilisateur(models.Model):
  user=models.OneToOneField('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  division=models.ForeignKey(Division, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

try this one. You tried to use "Division" which is a reserved keyword because of your imports. You should never name variables with capital letters though, unless you want to define constants.